# How to use a table of column names in a select statement

Tags: information-schema

I have a table that I will add columns to in the future and don't want to update all my queries when they're added.  I'm grabbing a set of column names using information_schema.COLUMNS and I want to use those names as the columns in a SELECT statement, but that's where I'm stuck:

```
select * into #Temp
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where column_name like '%search_string%' and table_name like 'searched_table'
select ...
```

So what's the syntax to use that table of column names after the SELECT, instead of listing each name individually?